# How to Stop execution of the JS Code after $.ajax call i.e. when server is processing the AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue in JQuery AJAX..

My Steps sequence are as follows:

1) I have a JS Function which I am calling on Button Click Event:

```
 function Click()
 {

    //I am performing some Validations then making an AJAX Request:

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: url, 
      context: window, 
      data: datatoPost,
      contentLength: contentLength, 
      async: true, 
      success: function (response) { 
          callbackFn(response); 
       },
      error: function (msg) { 
          this.error = msg;
       }
    });

   // The callback function is called on Successfull AJAX Request 
   // i.e. callbackFn (See below)

   // I am then checking the window.IsValid which I have set in below function;

   if (window.IsValid == true) {
           // Then Perform another AJAX Request
     }
     else {
         // do nothing
     }
  }


  function callbackFn(response)
  {
     if(response == 'Valid')
     {
         window.IsValid = true;
     }
     else 
     {
         window.IsValid = false;
     }
  }
```

2) Now, The Problem is while **server is processing the First AJAX Request then the code written after that i.e. 
                     if (window.IsValid == true) {
                   // Then Perform another AJAX Request
                     }
                     else {
                    // do nothing
                    }
                   }
is executed**

3) I get **window.IsValid = false** as first AJAX Request's callback function i.e. **callbackFn(response)** is not called yet and Even after a Valid response of first AJAX request my second ajax request is not getting executed as **window.IsValid** variable is not still got set in callback function as callback is not called yet due to server is processing the request.

Please help me I am stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should then use

```
async: false,
```

in you ajax function call. Which is not recomended. The better thing will be to use

```
if (window.IsValid == true) {
           // Then Perform another AJAX Request
     }
     else {
         // do nothing
     }
  }
```

within your callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Actually My scenario is different. I understand that another thing should be done is success function but Second AJAX request is in another user control and I am injecting this script there and if I can be able to set the IsValid property in click (example) function then its would be fine but due to different scenrio and after ajax request, callback function will be called so I had to set the window variable to access in the example function i.e. click().

Comment: user160820, Please tell me why async: false is not recommended. IF you are telling this because another execution of the browser will be stopped ? If it is then thats what I needed, I don't want the user to perform another action, user has to wait for the first ajax request to complete.

Comment: Because of the nature of the Javascript. That's why javascript offers callback functions. 
It's not a best practice, but forbidden it is not :) You can use
async:false in your sitution.

Comment: Thanx for the awesome answers guys.. user160820, I have set async to false and That solved my problem.. Thanx again.. I really appreciate. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because your post is asynchronous, the script continues to execute whilst the ajax request is being processed.

Instead, you need to move your tests for window.IsValid into the success function:

```
function Click()
{
   //I am performing some Validations then making an AJAX Request:

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: url, 
      context: window, 
      data: datatoPost,
      contentLength: contentLength, 
      async: true, 

      success: function (response) { 
          callbackFn(response); 

          if (window.IsValid == true) {
              // Then Perform another AJAX Request 
              // best done as another function.
          }
          else {
              // do nothing
          }
       },

      error: function (msg) { 
          this.error = msg;
      }
   });
}
```